# How to change background of a layout using image from SD card through java code?

Tags: android

I loaded image from sd card through this code

```
 public void browseImages(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&&data!=null){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmapImage  = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
            previewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and tried to set background using this code in other activity

```
public void background(){
       BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(MainActivity.bitmap);
        imageLayout.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
    }
```

but it is not working
Thanks in advance

Comment: According to your code you have not set bitmap image in bitmap variable of Main Activity so set it

Comment: One of the reason of not showing up is because the bitmap that your are try to load is too big. Try the code with a smaller bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling wrong method `setBackground()` change to `setBackgroundDrawable()`

Like this

```
public void background(){
       BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(MainActivity.bitmap);
        imageLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: this is not working 'BitmapDrawable(android.graphics.Bitmap)' is deprecated but thanks anyway